# jquery validate notEqualTo added method

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

From another, older stack post that looked like it would do exactly as needed, I added a method to validator that (should) compare an input to a list of banned values and then return an error message if the input is on the list.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('notEqualTo',function(value, element, param) {
    var notEqual = true;
    value = $.trim(value);
      for (i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
        if (value == $.trim($(param[i]).val())) { notEqual = false; }
      }
      return this.optional(element) || notEqual;
        },"The value you entered is not permitted in this field.");
```

The problem seems to be in the comparison.  No matter what I specify as the banned value, this always returns true, when it looks like it should return false on a match.

```
userloginname: {
    required: true,
    notEqualTo: ['password','anotherword','#email']
```

Using the above, if the user entered "password", "anotheword", or the username matched the e-mail field, it should set notEqual = false and throw the error.

Comment: Where is the relevant HTML markup of your form?

Comment: Look closely at [the documentation for `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and you'll see your mistake.  You do not need `.val()` to compare one variable to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be treating strings that represent words and strings that represent the `id` of another element as the same thing.

```
notEqualTo: ['password','anotherword','#email']
```

The root problem for the first two parameters is here:

```
if (value == $.trim($(param[i]).val()))
```

1. `.val()` is only [for retrieving the value of a form element](http://api.jquery.com/val/).  You are incorrectly attaching it to `param` which is a variable that represents a word.
2. Wrapping `param[i]` within a jQuery function, `$()`, turns this variable into a jQuery object, which is what you don't need in the case of the firs two parameters.

Simply compare the two variables...

```
if (value === param[i])
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/kwxtvur8/](https://jsfiddle.net/kwxtvur8/)**

That being said, if your third parameter is the value of another field, then you'll need to handle this separately from the other parameters that are strings.  I recommend one method to handle comparing the value to words (as in my demo), and another totally separate method for comparing the value of this field to another field's value.

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        userloginname: {
            required: true,
            notEqualTo: ['password', 'anotherword'],
            notEqual: '#email'
        }
    } 
    ....
```

`notEqual` method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('notEqual', function(value, element, param) {
    value = $.trim(value);
    return this.optional(element) || (value !== $.trim($(param).val()));
}, "The value you entered is not permitted in this field.");
```

DEMO 2:  [jsfiddle.net/hp1dgcug/](https://jsfiddle.net/hp1dgcug/)

Comment: Thank you @Sparky!  You've explained it in a way that even a dabbler like myself can understand and that is much appreciated!